# How to show all data form users table only when its detail doesnot exist in user_details table in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have two table one **users** and other **user_details**.

**Users** table `id,name,phone,email`

**user_details** table `id, user_id, address, city`

I am saving `id` of a user in `user_details` as `user_id`

I want to show all users data only when users have not updated their `user_details` table.

How can I possibly achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

## has() - used for getting on users having user details

## doesntHave() - used for getting user doesn't have user details

In your User Model make a relation

```
public function details(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail');
}
```

When you fetch users in controller

```
User::has('details')->with('details')->get();
```